# The three forces acting on the beam can be replaced with a single equivalent force R. Determine the angle θ and R.

Tags: vectors, physics, education

[image]

I was able to come up with the below equations but after the last one, regarding the moment of resultant, I got stuck.

F<sub>*x*</sub> = 25kNcos(40) + 60kNcos(θ) - 80kNcos(50)

F<sub>*y*</sub> = 25kNsin(40) + 60kNsin(θ) + 80kNsin(50)

∑M<sub>*o*</sub> = Rd

[Moment at P<sub>*2*</sub> point.]

Rd = -25sin(40)(4) + 80sin(50)(6)

Answer (score -1):

Solve for theta first then solve sum of Fx and Fy:

[image]